# I have an array of dictionary with keys prefix @ like

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@{@"@Add" : @"Sheikh Zayed Road,Dubai",
                                   @"@Front_Image" : @"http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/920000/919000/918930/918930_81_z.jpg",
                                   @"@HDes" : @"Property Location-With a stay at Shangri-La Hotel ",
                                   @"@HIndex" : @5,
                                   @"@HName" : @"ShangriLa Hotel Dubai",
                                   @"@Lattitude" : @"25.20798",
                                   @"@Longitude" : @"55.27221",
                                   @"@Max_Price" : @"261.73",
                                   @"@Min_Price" : @"1960.02",
                                   @"@Star_Rating" : @5,
                                   @"@TripAdvisor" : @"4.5 Out of 5 ( 1122 reviews )",
                                   @"@TripAdvisorURL" : @"http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/4.5-12345-4.gif",
                                   @"@Type" : @"Hotels"}
```

I want to sort it in descending order with `@HIndex` key but getting the following error

```
[<__NSCFDictionary 0x7fcf75801af0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HIndex.'
```

My code is

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"@HIndex" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.arrHotelResults sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]]];
```

Comment: And the code used for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort like this

```
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [arrHotelResults sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
  return [obj1[@"@HIndex"] compare:obj2[@"@HIndex"]];
}].mutableCopy;
```

Comment: paul code is working fine but when the number of digits changed it fails like if the @HIndex is like 2,3,4,5,8,9 then its working fine but when the array is like 4,5,3,6,7,1,2,12,11 then the output comes 1,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: I'm assuming your example code is wrong then. This would happen if `@HIndex` is not an `NSNumber` but instead an `NSString`. If so you'll need to change the comparison to `return [obj1[HIndexKey] compare:obj2[HIndexKey] options:NSNumericSearch];`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use `@` in KVC Collection. The `@` in a key path, it denotes a particular aggregate function, e.g. `@count` 、 `@sum` etc.

> Simple Collection Operators
>
> @count: Returns the number of objects in the collection as an NSNumber.
>
> @sum: Converts each object in the collection to a double, computes the sum, and returns the sum as an NSNumber.
>
> @avg: Takes the double value of each object in the collection, and returns the average value as an NSNumber.
>
> @max: Determines the maximum value using compare:. Objects must support comparison with one another for this to work.
>
> @min: Same as @max, but returns the minimum value in the collection.
>
> http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Instead, you can use `NSComparator` like so:

```
NSString *key = @"@HIndex";
NSArray *results = [arrHotelResults sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 objectForKey:key] > [obj2 objectForKey:key]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 objectForKey:key] < [obj2 objectForKey:key]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

Here are my test data:

```
NSArray *arrHotelResults = @[
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @5, @"@HName" : @"XYZ Plaza Hotel Dubai"},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @3, @"@HName" : @"Beijing"},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @10, @"@HName" : @"Xiamen"},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @2, @"@HName" : @"Wuhan"},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @1, @"@HName" : @"Taj Palace"}
                             ];
```

Comment: I have posted my test data. I want to know why it's not working.

Comment: when i am using your test code its working but when i am using your code with my array its not . I have updated my array please try with that

Comment: Can you post your full array in GitHub Gist?